# How can I automatically revert a file's ownership when changed?

Tags: daemon, ownership

I have a file that is periodically updated by vendor software.  When this happens, it changes the group ownership, and my internal system can no longer read it.

Is there a simple way to update the ownership whenever this file is changed?  Perhaps something with `auditd`?

I understand this is just a stop-gap.

Comment: How often vendor software do this? Make cron which do `chown` more frequently

Comment: Maybe change your "internal system" so it could read it, instead of changing the file's ownership? On linux, you can probably use `inotity(7)` or `fanotify(7)` or a combination of both to monitor (and change) fs events, but it sounds like absolute overkill.

Comment: Have you tried fIlesystem ACLs and give access to your group that way?

Comment: If the vendor update is changing the ownership, it is more likely they are actually removing and re-creating the file. You could note the inode number before and after the next occurrence of the problem.